# iPhone Dead, No Charger

Tags: iphone, charging

Someone dropped their iPhone near my door. The neighbor picked it up, phoned me, and told me it has my number in it so it's probably someone I know.

But now, the phone is dead, and I don't have an iPhone charger to charge it. How can I turn this thing on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the nearest Apple store and ask to use one of their chargers. From my previous experiences, they are usually very helpful.

Comment: @ashes999 Similarly go to any place (events, other stores, etc) prone to find apple folks (fans, employees, etc) and you'll most likely be able to borrow a charge for long enough.

Answer (score 1):

As popular as iDevices are I would think that you would be able to find someone with one that is close by... heck I can think of 5 people at work, off the top of my head plus myself...

Comment: If it was that easy, I wouldn't need to ask this question.